# Limiting the formatting options in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

This is my TinyMCE code:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    //plugins : "safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,
    // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    //content_css : "css/example.css",
    // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
    template_external_list_url : "js/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url : "js/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url : "js/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url : "js/media_list.js",
    // Replace values for the template plugin
    template_replace_values : {
        username : "Some User",
        staffid : "991234"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also want to set:

```
theme_advanced_buttons2 : ""
theme_advanced_buttons3 : ""
```